# I want to extract text from the following sentences

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I want to extract text from the sentences in python using pattern i do not want to use the key to extract  because my data is very dynamic following is my data following a specific pattern

```
data = [
    "transaction approval ON 09/24 ABC Y 50 420 Address Address CT Transaction-id CARDnumber 3412",
    "transaction approval ON 08/24 CATR 55 490 Address Address CT Transaction-id CARDnumber 7631",
    "transaction approval ON 10/24 skt Address Address ND Transaction-id CARDnumber 9801",
]
```

from the data i want to extract only
`ABC Y CATR skt` as a separate column

currently i am using this pattern `r"transaction approval ON \d+/\d+ ([A-Z]+(?: [A-Z]+)?) \d+"`
but the pattern is not working can anyone help on this regard

Comment: [It is working](https://ideone.com/mvE64b), isn't it? What does your Pandas code look like?

Comment: I have several patterns that works fine on my pandas but only this pattern is not working so it's the issue with the pattern @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Well, and you can add `a-z` to capture lower case letters, so you also get the `skt`

Comment: can you please edit it for me as i am unable to map @Dr.V

Comment: It is not clear **how** it should work, but trying to accommodate to your expected output, I have come up with https://ideone.com/MQOWIe

Comment: I am really not sure why this suggested is not running on my laptop but it runs on colab @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: I have no idea. At this point, the question is just way too unclear.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew so, here is the question, I have few transaction details row by row i can see that the first transaction happened at ABC Y 2nd transaction happened at CATR and 3rd happend at skt 

so i want to strip all these 3 names (ABC Y CATR skt) into separate column called transactions

Comment: But it is only **you**, a *human*, who "*can see*" that. How is the regex engine supposed to know that? What are the rules to implement? What to match? What are the boundaries?

Answer (score -1):

Try using this regex pattern, which will capture any characters between "ON MM/YY" and "Address.":

```
pattern = r'ON \d{2}/\d{2} (.*?) Address'
```

Also, to remove the non-digit characters from the captured string you can add a filter:

```
''.join(filter(lambda x: x.isdigit() == False , ' '.join(matches)))
```

Here's the full code:

```
from typing import List
import re

def extract_letters(data: List[str]) -> List[str]:
    extracted_letters = []

    # Define the regex pattern to capture letters between "ON MM/YY" and "Address"
    pattern = r'ON \d{2}/\d{2} (.*?) Address'

    for entry in data:
        # Use re.findall to find all occurrences of the pattern in each entry
        matches = re.findall(pattern, entry)

        # Extracted letters may not contain digits, so filter only non-digit characters
        letters = ''.join(filter(lambda x: x.isdigit() == False , ' '.join(matches)))

        # Append the cleaned letters to the result list
        extracted_letters.append(letters.strip())

    return extracted_letters

data = [
    "transaction approval ON 09/24 ABC Y 50 420 Address Address CT Transaction-id CARDnumber 3412",
    "transaction approval ON 08/24 CATR 55 490 Address Address CT Transaction-id CARDnumber 7631",
    "transaction approval ON 10/24 skt Address Address ND Transaction-id CARDnumber 9801",
]

result = extract_letters(data)

print(result)
```